# RegionIntersection runs for a very long time and then aborts without returning a result

Tags: performance-tuning, regions, mesh, computational-geometry

Is there a good strategy to speed up `RegionIntersection` computations like the one below:

```
ClearAll[reg1, reg2, res];
reg1 = Parallelepiped[
    {-223.812, -231.195, -3449.08},
    {
        {117.905, -236.219, -163.835},
        {-37.0885, -477.182, 661.318},
        {1056.68, 324.114, 293.13}
    }
];
reg2 = Polyhedron[{
    {
        {1231.48, 357.95, -4211.93},
        {-357.48, 135.948, -4812.15},
        {-702.666, 566.55, -4057.59}
    },
    {
        {-1159.38, -1559.96, -2061.98},
        {846.6, -756.866, -337.978},
        {853.676, -702.691, -322.517},
        {-1420.85, 64.8043, -1970.76}
    },
    {
        {1999.35, -2007.18, -2510.94},
        {3018.78, -199.677, -3076.07},
        {853.676, -702.691, -322.517},
        {846.6, -756.866, -337.978}
    },
    {
        {846.6, -756.866, -337.978},
        {-1159.38, -1559.96, -2061.98},
        {-518.838, -2359.01, -3462.16},
        {1999.35, -2007.18, -2510.94}
    },
    {
        {1231.48, 357.95, -4211.93},
        {-702.666, 566.55, -4057.59},
        {-1420.85, 64.8043, -1970.76},
        {853.676, -702.691, -322.517},
        {3018.78, -199.677, -3076.07}
    },
    {
        {-702.666, 566.55, -4057.59},
        {-357.48, 135.948, -4812.15},
        {-518.838, -2359.01, -3462.16},
        {-1159.38, -1559.96, -2061.98},
        {-1420.85, 64.8043, -1970.76}
    },
    {
        {3018.78, -199.677, -3076.07},
        {1999.35, -2007.18, -2510.94},
        {-518.838, -2359.01, -3462.16},
        {-357.48, 135.948, -4812.15},
        {1231.48, 357.95, -4211.93}
    }
}];
res = RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2];
(* Computes forever, before aborting *)
```

In my problem, `reg2` is constant, and I need to compute its intersection with many smaller regions of the kind in `reg1`.

So far, the only strategy that I have found to speed up the computation--and, indeed, to return a result at all--is to compute axis-aligned `BoundingRegion`s. But then the errors are much larger.

Windows 11, Mathematica 13.2, 12th generation i9, 64 GB of 4800 MHz DDR5 RAM (so the hardware should not really be the problem here)

**How reg2 was obtained**

I first obtained two PDB files from RCSB PDB. Here are the PDB files, uploaded to Google Drive for your convenience:

[PD1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OHV9r_ykrVAy6KArFNeccTG3fdO3fjjp/view?usp=share_link)

[PDL1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JVFjKqR1X0FdXPUgphZDrG-1kTzGyyHv/view?usp=share_link)

Then I obtained the `BoundingRegion` for each of these and computed the intersection as follows:

```
ClearAll[pd1coords, pdl1coords, reg2];
pd1coords = Import[pd1File, {"PDB", "VertexCoordinates"}];
pdl1coords = Import[pdl1File, {"PDB", "VertexCoordinates"}];
reg2 = {pd1coords, pdl1coords} // (
    Map[BoundingRegion[#, "FastOrientedCuboid"] &] /*
    Apply[RegionIntersection]
);
```

Comment: I think "Polyhedron"  is not a primitive for regions, Only "UniformPolyhedron" is.

Comment: @DanielHuber, `reg2` was actually obtained by intersecting two `BoundingRegion[coords, "FastOrientedCuboid"]` expressions. Is `RegionIntersection` not a closed operator?

Comment: `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[reg2]]` shows that the Polyhedron is not valid. Can you show how you obtained `reg2`?

Comment: @user21 please see the edit above.

Comment: I think this is a question Wolfram should answer. Report it to: support@wolfram.com and let us know what they say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**

```
$Version
13.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)
```

```
reg3 = ConvexHullRegion[Flatten[reg2[[1]], 1]];
Manipulate[
 Show[Region[
   Style[RegionIntersection[
     TransformedRegion[reg1, TranslationTransform[t {1, 1, 1}]], 
     reg3], Red]], Graphics3D[Style[reg3, Opacity[.2]]]], {t, -1000, 
  600}]
```

[image]

**Original**

It seems that the problem come from `reg2`.

```
reg3 = ConvexHullRegion[Flatten[reg2[[1]], 1]]
intersection = RegionIntersection[reg1, reg3]
RegionMeasure[intersection]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, in my `TimeConstrained` run, this fails to return a result in 30 seconds. In fact, the kernel still aborts. How long did it take your computer to return a result?

Comment: @Shredderroy  Only 1 seconds.

Comment: Hmm...fascinating! I have restarted my kernel, but something seems to be off...

Comment: @Shredderroy  My code also work fine in v13.2 on  Linux Mint 21.1.

Comment: @Shredderroy with `13.2.0` on macOS I managed to run the suggested solution by cvgmt very quickly

Comment: Somehow, I got a result this time. But my intersection is a `Polyhedron` with `Number of points: 10` and `Number of faces: 16`, which is not what is shown in @cvgmt 's response. Can you please post your `RegionMeasure`? I get `1.37373 x 10^10` for the `RegionMeasure` of my intersection. I literally copied and pasted what you did.

Comment: @Shredderroy  updated.